# hi, my photo keeps on getting cropped when I add it, but I really need it fully, how do I do?

Tags: entries

I made a new entry for my website, and I added a photo in "flexible", it's a png, and it does show the image where I want to, but it keeps getting cropped, and no matter how I crop it myself or how I download it, it's still cropped and I can't see what I need in the photo. Is there any way to have the whole photo shown?

Answer (score 1):

The output of images is determined by the template. It's possible to force exact dimensions or a specific aspect ratio for an image in the template, which is sometimes done to ensure an image fits nicely in a particular component or layout.

If the template crops images to a specific aspect ratio, you can't change that from the backend. If the template uses a [defined transform](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/image-transforms.html), you might be able to change that through the CMS settings, but it's easy to mess something up here if you don't know what you're doing. And if the template explicitly crops images to specific dimensions, this can only be changed in the template.

Do you have a developer to make those kinds of changes for you?